# iOS Game Center: Creating Lifetime Achievements

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, game-center

I'm trying to add a Lifetime achievement to my iOS app. That is, how many times the user performed the single action since he played the game for the first time. In other words, how many kills he got since... ever. I'm using the code based on the one provided by Apple:

.h file:

```
int64_t  lifetimeScore;

IBOutlet UILabel *lifetimeScoreLabel;
```

.m file:

```
- (IBAction) increaseScore {
     self.lifetimeScore = self.lifetimeScore + 1;
     lifetimeScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", self.lifetimeScore];

  // Saving the Score:

    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:lifetimeScore forKey: @"Score"];
    [defaults synchronize];


    [self checkAchievements]; }


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  

// Loading the Lifetime Score:

    self.lifetimeScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"Score"];

    lifetimeScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", self.lifetimeScore];


(...)
}
```

I works great, no warnings, but each time I close the app, deletes it from the Multitask bar and open the app again, the lifetimeScore goes back to zero. I'm trying to save the int_64 using NSUserDefaults but so far I can't make it work... any ideas?

EDIT: The code was fixed and now it's working 100% in case anyone wants to use it. The complete source code can found here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-2/

Comment: Should the last line say @"Store" or @"Score"? Maybe it is working, it just cant find the key.

Comment: Thanks!!!! Good news: that was the problem!!!! Bad news: Lost 2 hours trying to find the error and it was a spelling error...

Comment: No problem, glad it was something simple :) I haven't messed with game center much yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@"Store" should be @"Score", just so I can get the points... :)